# How to Implement Delphi Tserversocket in Multithread mode

Tags: multithreading, sockets, delphi

I Want To create a TCP/Server and receive data from Multiple Clients in text Format.Data Length is never more than 1024 chars.
I am using the follow code But i am not sure is the correct way i think sould be a easiest way like myString=Socket.ReceiveText 
I am excpecting around 100+ simulate connections. 
Is it anything i can to for make it better?

indy is not a choice and i am working in **Delphi 5**

```
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  ScktComp, Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
      var ErrorCode: Integer);
    procedure ServerSocket1GetThread(Sender: TObject;
      ClientSocket: TServerClientWinSocket;
      var SocketThread: TServerClientThread);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TClientThread = class(TServerClientThread)
  private
    Received_text: string;
    fsocketStream: TWinsocketStream;
  public
    procedure ClientExecute; override;
  end;



var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TClientThread.ClientExecute;
var
  Data: array[0..1023] of char;
begin

inherited FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;

      fsocketStream := TWinSocketStream.Create(ClientSocket, 1000);
      try

  while not Terminated and ClientSocket.Connected do
    try

        FillChar(Data, SizeOf(Data), 0);
        try
          if fsocketStream.Read(Data, SizeOf(Data)) = 0 then
            begin
              ClientSocket.Close;
              Terminate;
            end;
        except
          ClientSocket.Close;
          Terminate;
        end;

        Received_text := Data;
     //Process Data HEre
     //process the data Like Read From SQL and Take actions Depence on data received
     //****************************************************************
        try ClientSocket.sendtext('Hello From MultiThread Server'); except end;

      finally
        fsocketStream.Free;

      end;
    except
      HandleException;
    end;



end;



procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  errorcode := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1GetThread(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TServerClientWinSocket;
  var SocketThread: TServerClientThread);
begin
  SocketThread := TClientThread.Create(False, ClientSocket);
end;

end.
```

here is a second Example.
I think for my meeds is better

```
Received_text:=Received_text+clientsocket.ReceiveText;
if pos(#13#10,Received_text)>0 Then
begin
try clientsocket.SendText(#13#10+'REC='+Received_text+#10#13);except end;
Received_text:='';
end;
```

Comment: Hi, other users will need more information before they can help you here. "Is it anything i can to for make it better?" is not specific enough. What problems have you experienced? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a useful guide to getting good results on SO.

Comment: "*I am using the follow code But i am not sure is the correct way*" - close, but you are making a couple of mistakes. Like dont create a new `TWinSocketStream` on each loop iteration. Create it once before entering the loop, free it after exiting the loop. "*i think sould be a easiest way like myString=Socket.ReceiveText*" - do not use `ReceiveText`. All it does is return whatever bytes are currently in the socket without regard to format or structure. TCP messages require structure, you need to code for that. "*indy is not a choice and i am working in Delphi 5*" - Indy supports Delphi 5.

Comment: thanks remy i corrected check teh second example this is without creating FsocketStream whats the wrong with this? I am going to have troubles in the feature if i use it? as i said users are sending plain text with LF on the end.
I know abou indy i used them a lot but in real world tclientsocket and tserversocket its much better for my needs.

Comment: "*as i said users are sending plain text with LF on the end*" - actually, you DIDNT say that earlier. That is important information to know. Now we can make progress. Your best option is to use `Socket.ReceiveBuf()` to read incoming data into a buffer, and then you can scan that buffer for `(CR)LF` so you are processing only complete strings. "*I know abou indy i used them a lot but in real world tclientsocket and tserversocket its much better for my needs"* - doubtful, they don't offer anything that Indy doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  ScktComp, Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
      var ErrorCode: Integer);
    procedure ServerSocket1GetThread(Sender: TObject;
      ClientSocket: TServerClientWinSocket;
      var SocketThread: TServerClientThread);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Winsock, RTLConsts;

{$R *.DFM}

type
  TClientThread = class(TServerClientThread)
  public
    procedure ClientExecute; override;
  end;

procedure TClientThread.ClientExecute;
var
  Data: array[0..1023] of AnsiChar;
  SocketStream: TWinSocketStream;
  Buffer, Received_text: AnsiString;
  NumRead, Len, Idx: Integer;

  procedure SendRaw(Buffer: Pointer; BufLen: Integer);
  var
    P: PByte;
    NumSent: Integer;
  begin
    // need to loop until all bytes are sent...
    P := PByte(Buffer);
    while BufLen > 0 do
    begin
      // TWinSocketStrea.Write() raises on failure, but returns 0 on timeout...
      NumSent := SocketStream.Write(P^, BufLen);
      if NumSent = 0 then
        raise ESocketError.CreateResFmt(@sSocketIOError, [sSocketWrite, WSAETIMEDOUT, SysErrorMessage(WSAETIMEDOUT)]);
      Inc(P, NumSent);
      Dec(BufLen, NumSent);
    end;
  end;

  procedure SendLine(const S: AnsiString);
  begin
    SendRaw(PAnsiChar(S), Length(S));
    SendRaw(PAnsiChar(#13#10), 2);
  end;

begin
  SocketStream := TWinSocketStream.Create(ClientSocket, 30000);
  try
    SendLine('Hello From MultiThread Server');

    while (not Terminated) and ClientSocket.Connected do
    begin
      // check if any new bytes have arrived...
      if not SocketStream.WaitForData(5000) then
        Continue;

      // TWinSocketStream.Read() raises on failure, and returns 0 on disconnect or timeout...
      NumRead := SocketStream.Read(Data, SizeOf(Data));
      if NumRead = 0 then
        Exit;

      // append new bytes to end of buffer...
      Len := Length(Buffer);
      SetLength(Buffer, Len + NumRead);
      Move(Data[0], @Buffer[Len+1], NumRead);

      // look for complete (CR)LF-delimited lines of text...
      repeat
        Idx := Pos(#10, Buffer);
        if Idx = 0 then Break; // not complete, wait for more bytes...

        Len := Idx-1;
        if (Len > 0) and (Buffer[Len-1] = #13) then
          Dec(Len); // ignore CR...

        Received_text := Copy(Buffer, 1, Len);
        Delete(Buffer, 1, Idx);

        //Process Received_text Here

        SendLine('REC=' + Str);
      until Buffer = '';
    end;
  finally
    SocketStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;
  var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  ErrorCode := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1GetThread(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TServerClientWinSocket;
  var SocketThread: TServerClientThread);
begin
  SocketThread := TClientThread.Create(False, ClientSocket);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Any way to have an example for this code with indy idTcpServer 9 or 10 ver?

Comment: @icinemagr edit your question to say that Indy is now a possible choice, and then I'll update my answer to include Indy examples.